# Mysql.connector in Python TypeError

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, byte, mysql-python

I have defined a Database class as follows:-

```
class Database(object):
    """ Implements all interactions with the DB. """

    def __init__(self, id_a, id_b, config):
        self.config = config
        self.id_a = id_a
        self.id_b = id_b
        self.db_connection = None
        self.cursor = None
        self.__init_db(config)

    def __init_db(self, config):
        """
        Initializes the MySQL Connector using the settings
        specified in the system configuration.

        """
        self.db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(user=config['database_user'],
                                                     password=config['database_password'],
                                                     host=config['database_host'],
                                                     database=config['database_name'])
        self.cursor = self.db_connection.cursor(dictionary=True,buffered=True)
        self.cursor.execute('SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;')
```

Now, when i define the below function to return the values fetched from the Mysql database i get an error

```
    def get_func(self):
        sql = "SELECT c_id FROM table \
        WHERE id_a = {} ".format(self.id_a)
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        rows = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if rows:
            for row in rows:
                ls1 = row['id_number']
            return ls1



    ls1 = row['id_number']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

in `row['id_number']` `row` is not a of type `dict`, but is of type `tuple`.

```
for row in rows:
    ls1 = row['id_number'] # error
```

in your case you do something like this

```
words = ('foo',)
words['id_number'] # error we need to pass only `int`

words[0] # right
# Output
# foo
```

also the `row` is single you don't need to use `for loop statment` just `row[0]`

```
row = self.cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    return row[0]
```

Comment: Can i do a `row = self.cursor.fetchall()` and use the dict type

Comment: why you need dict type ? if you select only `c_id` from `table` and use only `fetchone()` simple return `row[0]` and it is all